# Задача о распределении команд по комнатам

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть такая вот задачка:
В первой строке записано целое число n — количество проектов в Периметре (2 ≤ n ≤ 1 000). Во второй строке записаны n целых чисел — площади всех комнат в новом офисе. В i-й из следующих n строк записаны два целых числа — минимальная и максимальная площади комнаты, в которой согласна сидеть команда i-го проекта (естественно, минимальная площадь не превосходит максимальной). Все указанные площади положительные и не превосходят 10 000.
Если существует единственный способ рассадить команды по комнатам так, чтобы все команды остались довольны, в первой строке выведите «Perfect!», а во второй строке — перестановку чисел от 1 до n. i-е число должно обозначать номер комнаты, которую должна занять команда i-го проекта. Комнаты занумерованы числами от 1 до n в том порядке, в котором они описаны во входных данных. Если возможных вариантов рассадки несколько, выведите «Ask Shiftman for help.» Если рассадить команды требуемым образом нельзя, выведите «Let's search for another office.»

Я придумал довольно странный код:

```
import sys
a = int(input())
squ = list(map(int,input().split()))
team = []
i = 0
while i < a:
    b = list(map(int,input().split()))
    team.append(b)
    i += 1
for j in range(len(squ)):
    c = 0
    for c in range(len(squ)):
        if squ[j] >= team[c][0] and squ[j] <= team[c][1]:
            del team[c]
            print('yes', j, c)
            break
        else:
            print('no')
            break
```

Но никак не могу придумать как сделать так чтоб он проверял комнаты и команды на совпадение и выводил все в правильном порядке! Надеюсь на помощь, может кто решал подобное и может скинуть код или объяснить какой алгоритм должен быть у решения! Спасибо)
Задача не учебная, просто для себя решаю изучая питон!
Тестовые значения:

```
3
40 50 60
30 70
20 40
60 60
```

Вывод должен быть:

```
Perfect!
2 1 3
```

Comment: Забыл добавить тестовые данные: 3, 40 50 60, 30 70, 20 40, 60 60. Пять строк на ввод получается

Comment: Вы можете редактировать свой вопрос.

Comment: Было бы неплохо если бы вы поделились ссылкой на проверяющую систему.

Comment: https://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1872

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команды и комнаты образуют двудольный граф, ребра в котором проведены от каждой команды ко всем подходящим комнатам. Для упрощения задания рёбер следует предварительно отсортировать комнаты по размеру.

Далее находится максимальное паросочетание в графе - например, методом [Хопкрофта-Карпа при использовании networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.matching.hopcroft_karp_matching.html#networkx.algorithms.bipartite.matching.hopcroft_karp_matching) или [метода Куна](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/kuhn_matching) при самостоятельной реализации. Если размер этого паросочетания совпадает с количеством команд `n`, то оно совершенное, и расстановка существует.

Теперь про единственность - имея совершенное паросочетание PM, пытаемся построить чередующийся ([картинка](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F:_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%85)) цикл (или цепь?), т.е. такой, ребра которого попеременно входят и не входят в PM. Если такой цикл найден, он представляет собой симметрическую разность между PM и неким другим совершенным паросочетанием, т.е. PM - не единственное решение.